# Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume

Tags: sql, cpanel

I have an sql file which I want to upload in my database in live server using Cpanel. The size of it is 8.36 mb. But the server showing me this error.

NB: I found several answers which shows me to configure php.ini file located in localhost. But in this case, I'm working with live server, and in the Cpanel I've no access in root files.

Comment: So did you resubmit the same file?

Comment: And how to do that? Have to import the file again?

Comment: Yes. The script says it'll continue where it had to stop. Try it (but make sure to check  the data afterwards, of course).

Comment: You can also compress the sql file into zip and import that. Sometimes this allows to avoid timeouts.

Comment: I have tried both with the file itself and compressed. But it shows the same issue. Its not working.

Comment: How to upload? Cpanel interface? Web script on your account? What it's your Apache + PHP Model?

Answer (score -1):

Please contact your hosting provider and ask them to increase max execution time and upload limit, You can not increase it with your cPanel access.

Comment: You know perhaps if the user is coming up with the file manager or a web script? If the last, you know if the server is in Suphp, or fastcgi mode, and have their porpio usuari opuede php.ini. One of his typical responses without sufficient data. Pure spam, to publicize their service Manego server, messing this site.